# How to make update data work really well?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use the Update Method in Firebase realtime database. Please someone help me figure out how to work it right?

Update Advertisement Method:-

```
private void UpdateAdvertisement(String tuitionimage, String tuitioname)
{
    HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
        userMap.put("adstuitionimage", tuitionimage);
        userMap.put("adstuitioname", tuitioname);
    updateAdvertisement.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
        {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                SendUserToViewAdsActivity();
                Toast.makeText(EditAdsActivity.this, "Advertisement has been updated successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(EditAdsActivity.this, "Error occured: Failed to save the updating advertisement data. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include what happened when you ran the code and what you expected to happen instead? Any errors? You may want  to take the [tour] to understand how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, we can make use of Intent class:

in your first activity where the data is already present,

ex: `String data = edit_text.getText().toString();`

So you can write:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("your_key", "" + data);   // Collected from EditText or any other source
...........
........... (You can have similar putExtras as many as you want)
startActivity(i);
```

then, in your Second Activity class,

in `onCreate()` method, write

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String data = i.getStringExtra("your_key"); // This key must be the same as from previous activity
............. (Similarly you can do for all)
```

Finally, use that data wherever you wish to update in firebase.

Hopefully it should work.